# Why can't I seem to remove undefined element from an array in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, list

I have an array of strings that comes from data in a hash table. I am trying to remove any (apparently) empty elements, but for some reason there seems to be an obstinate element that refuses to go.

I am doing:

```
# Get list array from hash first, then
@list = grep { $_ ne ' ' } @list; 
@list = uniq @list;
return sort @list;
```

At the `grep` line I get the `Use of uninitialized value in string ne...` message with the rest of the array printed correctly below.

I've tried doing it the 'long' way:

```
foreach (@list) {
    if ($_ ne ' ') {
        push @new_list, $_;
    }
}
```

But this produces exactly the same result. I tried using `defined` with the expected result (nothing).

I could sort the array beforehand and delete the first element, but that seems very risky as I cannot guarantee that the data set will always have blank elements. It also seems excessive to resort to regular expressions, but perhaps I'm wrong. I'm sure I'm missing something ridiculously simple, as usual.

Comment: I should add that the blank element actually is a space. That is why I'm testing for it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My answer assumes that you do not want strings that are either empty (meaning undefined or have a length of 0) or consist solely of spaces.

Your `grep` line only tests for strings that equal exactly one space. However, the warning implies that at least one array element is indeed `undefined`. Comparing an undefined value with `eq` will only yield true for an empty string, not for a single space.

So in order to remove all entries that are either undefined or consist only of spaces you could do something like this:

`@list = grep { defined && m/[^\s]/ } @list;`

Note that an empty space is trueish for Perl. Therefore a simple `grep defined, @list` will actually not throw out the entries that consist solely of spaces.

Comment: Could you explain the `!m/$\s+$/` part? I get a `Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string...` for every iteration. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I made two mistakes. Sorry for that. I've corrected them. The first, `$_`, matches everything that is defined and not empty. The second part is the corrected regular expression `m/^\s+$/`. It means: `^` match from the start of the string, `\s+` one or more white space (spaces & tabs), `$` until the end of the string. Meaning all strings consisting solely of whitespaces will be skipped as well.

Comment: `/\S/` is simpler than `!m/^\s+$/`.

Comment: or `/\w/` to check for anything meaningful (`[0-9a-zA-Z_]`)

Comment: This will also remove elements that are a single `0` character.

Comment: Oops, indeed. I've fixed the statement accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Elements can't be empty. You're trying to remove *undefined* elements. But you're not checking if the element is undefined, you're checking if it consists of a string consisting of a single space. You want:

```
@list = grep defined, @list;
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to filter all the elements that contain a non-space character. To do this as well as reject undefined elements you can write simply

```
@list = uniq grep { defined and /\S/ } @list;
```